# Why the fileName of MultipartFile which is uploaded is empty

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload

I want to import a file to server. But the fileName of MultipartFile which is uploaded is always empty. Following is my code.

XML

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="${web.maxUploadSize}" />  
</bean>
```

JSP

```
<form id="importForm" action="${url}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
         style="padding-left:20px;text-align:center;" onsubmit="loading('Please wait...');"><br/>
        <input id="uploadFile" name="file" type="file" style="width:330px"/>
</form>
```

JAVA

[image: JAVA code and debug info]

What caused fileName empty? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Which navigator are you using?

Comment: Can you use a network analyser such as wireshark to inspect if the filename is even transmitted by the browser?

Comment: @Arthur Noseda, I have checked this problem on both firefox and chrome. But they didn`t work.

Comment: Pretty in line with what the javadoc says, so far. You could test with Opera to prove the point.

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc for [MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename--), `getOriginalFilename()` may contain path information depending on the browser used, but it typically will not with any other than Opera.